# Is there a way to pass an initial value to gdal.RasterizeLayer in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I have tried `gdal.RasterizeLayer(..., options=['INIT=1'])`,
but it's ignored. I know that some preferences like
`options=['ATTRIBUTE={}'.format(att_name)])`,
or `burn_values=[1]` can be set, so I thought there should be something similar for initial values; not to mention there's a `-init val` option for the `gdal_rasterize` commandline tool. I also tried lower case init with no success.

Comment: Any reason you are using the low-level `gdal.RasterizeLayer` instead of the newer `gdal.Rasterize` function which is much easier to use?

Comment: yes, I have created the first argumnet ```destNameOrDestDS``` the way I want, with the number of pixels, trans, proj, ..., yet ```gdal.Rasterize``` complains that either ```-tr xres yres```  or ```-ts xsize ysize``` is required. I could try giving the number of pixels, but seems a bit fishy that it doesn't read that info from the destDs. I don't have this issue with ```gdal.RaserizeLayer.```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an initial value to `gdal.RasterizeLayer`.

You can pass an initial value to `gdal.Rasterize` *if* you pass it a filepath (string) and let it create the output raster.  This won't use an existing raster, it will recreate it so you need to pass in the appropriate resolution and extent etc. flags.

As you already have an open `Dataset` object, you can pass that in to either `gdal.RasterizeLayer` or `gdal.Rasterize` and you won't need to pass in any resolution or extent etc. parameters, gdal will read that from the dataset.  However, you will need to set the initial value manually using the `RasterBand.Fill` method, like below:

```
init_value = 99
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', 4000, 4500, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(init_value)
```

A worked example using `gdal.Rasterize`:

```
from osgeo import (gdal, ogr, osr)

sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(3577)
sr_wkt = sr.ExportToWkt()

init_value = 99
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTIFF').Create('/tmp/test.tif', 4000, 4500, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(init_value)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((1526014, 10, 0, -3945766, 0, -10))
target_ds.SetProjection(sr_wkt)
vector_ds = gdal.OpenEx('/tmp/test.shp')
gdal.Rasterize(target_ds, vector_ds, bands=[1], attribute='id', layers=['test'])

target_ds = None
```

[image]

Comment: Great! ```band.Fill(val)``` does it. I was thinking of ```band.Write(array)```, but this is much better. Thanks.